# Is this a good use of JQuery's queues?

Tags: jquery, ajax, queue

I have a page with a list of users for whom I want to fetch an icon showing their Skype status as determined by http://mystatus.skype.com/mediumicon/.

In developing this, I've found that the the calls to mystatus.skype.com tend to fail when I send them all at once.

So I'm trying to implement it such that after the page loads, the calls to mystatus.skype.com happen in the background at some specific interval (like 0.4 seconds or so), and if the calls time out, it'll keep trying.

Does this seem like it would be a good use for JQuery's [queue](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) functionality? Does anyone have any examples of any implementations of something like this? Or is this a misguided approach?

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using jQuery `queue` I would suggest you to use `setInterval` which will call the passed function at a specified interval. jQuery queue is executed in a sequence instead of repetitively calling a function which is what you are looking for. I hope this makes a sense.

```
setInterval(function(){
   alert("I am called every 0.4 seconds");
}, 400);
```

Comment: Good point, although I think I need to do them in a sequence AND repetitively (if the calls fail).